# Whale Length Puzzle

Tags: mathematics, logical-deduction

A whale has 15 meters of length. Her head is as big as her tail. If her head was two times longer than it actually is, her head and her tail, together, would be as long as the rest of her body (i.e., the part that is between the head and the tail). What is the length of her head, tail and the rest of the body?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This isn't really a puzzle, but:

> Let H,B be the lengths of the head and body. The tail is of length H. If the head were twice as long then head+tail would be 3H, so B=3H. So total length is H+3H+H=5H and H=3m; the tail is the same length and the body is (as stated above) 3H = 9m.